# Find user ID's who appear in a certain period and not in another

Tags: mysql, sql, between, self-join

Given a table `tbl_orders` containing order details for many months, what's the most efficient SQL query to get a list of user ID's `userID` who appear in a given period `BETWEEN 2019-01-01 AND 2019-01-31` but don't appear in another period `BETWEEN 2019-02-01 AND 2019-02-28`.

Date column is `orderDate`

I tried self join but it returns nothing

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.userID
FROM tbl_orders a,
     tbl_orders b
WHERE a.orderDate BETWEEN 2019-01-01 AND 2021-01-31
  AND b.orderDate
    NOT BETWEEN 2019-02-01 AND 2019-02-28;
```

Comment: First of all, you should quote the date literals.

Comment: When you don't put the dates into quotes , `MySQL` is doing arithmetic operations so `2019-01-01` is equal to `2017` and `2021-01-31` equal to `1989` . So you are doing `WHERE a.orderDate BETWEEN 2017 AND 1989`

Comment: @ErgestBasha
Thanks a lot.
Quotation was the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NOT EXISTS

Your dates are wrong the **must** have a single quote

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.userID
FROM tbl_orders a 
WHERE a.orderDate BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2021-01-31'
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tbl_orders WHERE orderDate
    BETWEEN '2019-02-01' AND '2019-02-28');
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly this one:

```
SELECT userID
FROM tbl_orders
WHERE orderDate BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-02-28'
GROUP BY userID
HAVING MAX(orderDate) <= '2019-01-31'
```